# Hashicorp Vault fails to start when using Godaddy certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to get the Hashicorp Vault UI to use HTTPS.  I have a certificate from Godaddy which works on the same machine in apache2.

My vault.hcl file looks as follows

```
# HTTPS listener
listener "tcp" {
  address       = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_cert_file = "/godaddy_certs/123xxx321.crt"
  tls_key_file = "/godaddy_certs/privatekey.key"
  tls_disable = "false"
}
```

However I read [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/configuration/listener/tcp#tls_cert_file) that I cannot simply use the certificate that was provided by Godaddy.  That reference say the following:

> *To configure the listener to use a CA certificate, concatenate the primary certificate and the CA certificate together. The primary certificate should appear first in the combined file.*

Now I am assuming that the "primary certificate" referred to here is the 123xxx321.crt file that was provided from Godaddy.  Godaddy also include a gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt file.

So I thought I could just create a new file called myVaultCert.crt and copy the PEM string from 123xxx321.crt which looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIG ... /0I=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

into the top position and then afterwards copy the PEM string from the gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt file.

So myVaultCert.crt now looks something like

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIG36F ... /0I=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEADC ... v08=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I change my vault.hcl config to look as follows:

```
# HTTPS listener
listener "tcp" {
  address       = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_cert_file = "/godaddy_certs/myVaultCert.crt"
  tls_key_file = "/godaddy_certs/privatekey.key"
  tls_disable = "false"
}
```

When I run `sudo systemctl start vault.service` I get the following returned:

> Job for vault.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
> See "systemctl status vault.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

When I check `journalctl -xe`  I see this

> Error initializing listener of type tcp: error loading TLS cert: decoded PEM is blank

So I went to Godaddy and saw there is a [repository](https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/) with links to root certificates and bundles etc etc.  I have tried to copy the certificate that was provided folowed by several Certificates found in that repository but they all give me the same error.

What certificates must I concatenate so that I can use a Godaddy certificate with Hashicorp Vault?

I have looked at these questions alrady but they do not seem to have the same issue as what I am experiencing.
[64697238](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64697238/ssl-certificate-configuration-in-hashicorp-vault) | [48791816](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48791816/hashicorp-vault-tls-cert-authentication-does-not-read-certificate?rq=2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error loading TLS cert: decoded PEM is blank

is completly missleading.  The problem was actually with my privatekey.key.

This is what I did to get Vault to work using a godaddy certificate.

1. I received a generated-private-key.txt when I setup the certificate on the Godaddy website.
2. I then downloaded the zip file from Godaddy which contained 3 files.

   - 123xxx321.crt
   - 123xxx321.pem
   - gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
3. I combined the primary certificate with the intermediate certificate into one file.

```
cat 123xxx321.crt gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt > myCert.crt
```

4. I removed the 4th certificate in the myCert.crt file.

> The 4th certificate in this file is redundant - as it is a self-signed root certificate, so cannot link trust from one CA to another. Including it is not harmful, but does make every TLS connection setup slightly longer for no benefit.
> 5. I copied the text out of the generated-private-key.txt file that was provided from Godaddy and pasted it into a myPrivateKey.pem file.
> 6. I change my vault.hcl file to look as follows:

```
# HTTPS listener
listener "tcp" {
  address       = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_cert_file = "/godaddy_certs/myCert.crt"
  tls_key_file = "/godaddy_certs/myPrivateKey.pem"
  tls_disable_client_certs = "true" # <-- Still checking if this is necessary
}
```

7. Started vault `sudo systemctl start vault.service`

Viola! ... It started with no errors.  I was able to browse to the correct url and I can see that it is secured by Godaddy.

Hope this helps someone.  I know I will need to refer to it in the future again!